# Are there ways to verify the cache that a hard disk have?

Tags: hard-drive, cache

Recently, I just brought a 500 GB hard disk. The sales person mention that the hard disk have a 32 MB cache.

I try using the PC-Wizard (http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/pc-wizard.html) as I heard from forum that it will display the Hard disk cache amount.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find that value under the 'Drives' section on the left panel.
(I tried running it with Administrative rights but still unable to find it. or is it that the hard disk have no cache and so the PC-Wizard does not show it?)

So, are there other freeware that can show me the cache size of the hard disk (regardless what brand and what size the hard disk is)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to just check the manufacturer's site, or even Google `<Your Drive Here> specs`. If you don't happen to know your drive's make and model, open up My Computer, right-click on the drive in question, go to Properties, and look under Hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You may want to try CrystalDiskInfo: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

It will show the cache of your HD and more info. It will read everything from SMART.